# waypoints between two path in polyline Google map android?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

hey i draw a path on map between two location successfully but i want to add way-point (like circle in picture on poly-line) but i don't know how to achieve this
[image]

how to draw circle or way points between path from A to B?
and then click on any circle drag and find new path?

Comment: I give you a hint. Type *Google Maps + Directions + waypoints* in Google, and check what comes up. FYI it takes less time to do that and click on the first result than to open a question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no attempt at all to find a solution before asking.

Comment: thanks for reply @MrUpsidown i search it for three day but not find solution so i ask him and i try it also it related to google map android not web so kindly if you have a solution then help me

Comment: Make an http request to the [Directions Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions).

Comment: yes i alreay use in and get response and draw path but how to add circle like in picture between path

Comment: Then [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=en#Waypoints) please. It's there. First page. It's called "Waypoints" as you could guess...

Comment: i read it and i know waypoints when i request it http i send two waypoint from A to B but the problem is that i dont know to add circles on polyline after some distance because i have two waypoint

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available on Android. What you could do, I suppose, is to add draggable markers for each waypoint, and make another directions request with the updated coordinates.